# Akryum:Vuex mapped action is not a function (typeError)

Tags: meteor, vue.js, vuex

"this.actionName" as a method is undefined in console.log yet error message says that its a typeError and isn't a function. I'm using meteor framework, with custom implementation of vuex.

Heres pastebin of what I thought would be relevant:
http://pastebin.com/zGfuqwxw

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/vuex-anybody-typeerror-thisstorecommit-is-not-a-function

That would be solution for basic vuex